# Generalization of "length measure"

Tags: measure-theory

I know that product measure construction yields measures that corresponds to the intuitive notion of "*area*", "*volume*" in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$ (as if obtained from Caratheodory + Hahn extension) from Lebesgue "*length*" measure on $\mathbb{R}$. I am wondering if we can have similar construction to define "*length*" on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. In other words, given measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ on $A, B$, is there a general definition of a measure $\mu$ on $A \times B$ such that the projections
\begin{align*}
\mu|_{A \times \{y\}} = \mu_1 \quad \forall y \in B\\
\mu|_{\{x\} \times B} = \mu_2 \quad \forall x \in A
\end{align*}
where such general constructions when applied to $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = \lambda$ (Lebesgue measure), $A = B = \mathbb{R}$ gives rise to *the "length"* measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: One difficulty is the projective sets.This is a family of subsets of $R$ that includes the Lebesgue sets and much more. From the topology on $R^2$ we define $B(R^2)$, the family of Borel sets in $R^2$. But the projection of a member of $B(R^2)$ onto a co-ordinate axis is not always a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $R$. (This is not obvious,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction you mention is not likely to work. There *is* a natural generalization of "length", namely Hausdorff measure.

Comment: I just realized that somehow the Euclidean geometry is built into the proposed construction. This makes is very unlikely to work in general.